# extract value from text file using php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract the price 44,380.86 between date and # using `preg_match_all()` from the following line.One more thing is date Jan 1, 2015 will be dynamic.Can someone tell me how to complete it?

`start on Jan 1, 2015                                 44,380.86    # of count: 15 tc`

Comment: between  '2015' and '44,380.86' is full of spaces?

Comment: @ttrasn yes it's uncertainty space

Comment: There's a non-regex way to do this. And in code it will actually have the benefit of being debuggable since u dont know regex

Comment: Anyway, what have you tried so far??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex ([regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/NNcOzQ/1)):

`start on\s[A-Za-z]+\s[1-9]+,\s[0-9]+\s+(.*?)\s+#`

**Example Code:**

```
<?php
preg_match_all(
    "/start on\s[A-Za-z]+\s[1-9]+,\s[0-9]+\s+(.*?)\s+#/",
    "start on Jan 1, 2015                                 44,380.86    # of count: 15 tc",
    $matches
);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be work for your problem with other changes:

```
preg_match_all("(\S+(?:\s\S+)*?)","Your string",$matches);
```

for your question you can use:

```
preg_match_all("(\S+(?:\s\S+)*?)","start on Jan 1, 2015                                 44,380.86    # of count: 15 tc",$matches);
echo $matches[5];
```

this regex parse your string with spaces, so when your string change, just you can edit index of `$matches` from `5` to what you want